# Integer-16 no longer sufficient in CoreData store

Tags: ios, core-data, integer

I have a Core Data attribute that I defined long ago as an Integer 16.  Recently users have come across an edge case in which the data stored can be >32768, resulting in unpredictable behavior.  It seems I can't change the attribute to an Integer 32 within a new Core Data model version.  What's the best way to deal with this issue and transition to an Integer 32 attribute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It is enough that you change the data type to Integer 32 in the data model. Of course, you will have to create a new version of the data model and use the lightweight migration method.

In the data model editor in Xcode, switch to Table style and simply choose the new data type from the popup menu beside the attribute name.

Comment: This worked, thanks.  Must have done something wrong the first time I tried this.